# Block popup on image hover using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want a popup block to appear when I hover over the image as given in the picture below. How can I achieve this using css.

I have already used css to change the background on hover so how can I make the content appear.

I have been using wordpress but I couldn't find any plugin for the same.

[image]

Can anyone help with this one?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you can't do this with **only** CSS : you have to use JS for it (so if you have not learned it before, I think you should...)

CSS can apply properties on elements "*selected*" but only that.
If you want to get an information about an element (like whether it is hovered) and apply a propertie to *another* element depending on the information (like `visibility:hidden`), you have to use JavaScript.